# SharePoint .doc files open as Template1 empty

Tags: 2013, word, office

I searched but couldn't find a solution to this.

I have a user that when browsing SharePoint documents library, they need to open .doc files.  The user has Office 2013 installed and SharePoint is running via `IE10 (Tried compatibility mode)`.  We cannot yet upgrade to `IE11` but this issue hasn't occurred for other users.

When the user clicks on the document it opens Word but only reaches the empty Template1 rather than opening the document.  If the user saves the document first then opens it from its location it open fine.

Anyone experienced this?  Thanks